# Deleting of 'd' and 'n' character in strip in python

Tags: python

dataframe

```
string1
Data%2Fxxx
Data%2Ffrance
Data%2Fdenmark
Data%2Fnorway
```

Code

```
df['string1'] = [x.strip('Data%2F') for x in df.string1]
```

output

```
string1
xxx
france
enmark
orway
```

So, **strip function is removing 'd' and 'n' first character.** 
Does anyone know why?
How can i stop this from removing?
Is this related to '\d' and '\n' ? 
   
python version - 3.7.4

Comment: I can see this problem in Python 3.6.8, I'm not using Pandas, just a normal list of strings

Comment: @AlexandreB. you're good, it's never bad to pin down version-specific behavior

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce with Python `3.7.3`

Comment: Looks like it might have to do with the `a%2F`, I get this curious result: `'a%2Fa'.strip(r'a\%2F')'; ''`

Comment: @AlexandreB. This is result for 3.7.4 python version

Comment: Just a note. Are you aware [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is not intended to work the way you are using it here? `strip` will reduce *any* of the characters in its argument string, and so it is not necessary to have two a's in it. (That said: the behavior you note is not consistent with this description.)

Comment: Does it behave as *described* (= not as you are using it) if you use [the correct syntax `x.str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)?

Comment: @usr2564301 right. I misunderstood the usage. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strip() method returns a copy of the string with both leading and trailing characters stripped. According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip, "The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped." Examples from the documentation:

```
    >>> '   spacious   '.strip()
    'spacious'
    >>> 'www.example.com'.strip('cmowz.')
    'example'
```

In other words, x.strip('Data%2F') is directing Python to strip any a's, t's, D's etc. from the beginning and end of the string. This is why `"Data%2Faloha".strip("Data%2F")` would actually return `'loh'` unless you have, say, a space at the end, which is not part of the chars argument in your example. This is my best guess as to what's happening for you.

Answer (score 1):

str.replace() should work perfectly for you.

```
>>> x.replace('Data%2F', '')
```

Comment: this is totally fine. But i wanna know why strip is behaving like that

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue but the [string.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) function is best suited to remove a few characters at the beginning and end of a given string. The characters you are trying to remove are all in the string ('Data%2F'). It could be the '%' character that can be throwing it off, but I don't have a definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to proceed is with string.replace()

**df['string1'] = [x.replace('Data%2F','') for x in dbppp.string1]**

The string.strip() method returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the beginning and the end of the string.

When I tested, it gave me a different result but still incorrect.

string.strip() is more used if you want to remove spaces from the start and end of a string for example.

Answer (score -1):

It should be because of \n if it happens with t as well. You should rather use replace because it won't get rid of whitespaces.

```
string.replace("Data%2F","")
```